# Trying to understand whether the app is taking too much memory in android

Tags: android, memory-management

I have been looking to `Logcat` output for memory performance. With the given data below, how should I understand whether my app is increasing or releasing it? Is it an acceptable performance?

```
07-23 14:52:05.910: D/dalvikvm(4909): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1332K, 25% free 7791K/10300K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 45ms
07-23 14:52:06.170: D/dalvikvm(4909): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1230K, 25% free 7811K/10300K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 44ms
07-23 14:52:06.360: D/dalvikvm(4909): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1222K, 24% free 7887K/10300K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 53ms
07-23 14:53:08.610: D/dalvikvm(4909): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1315K, 22% free 8061K/10300K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 99ms
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell whether it's acceptable performance without context. What does your app do, what sort of data do you handle? Do you handle images (i.e. Bitmaps) a lot, is it just text, etc.?

Comment: I handle images a lot.

Comment: Right, in that case I think your memory usage is pretty standard. If you want to investigate further, this tool is great for seeing where your memory is going. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#ViewingAllocations

Comment: I'll have a look to it

Answer (score 1):

There is a monitor app that comes with the Android SDK. You can use to to look at the memory that your app is using. Take a look at this post on the [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with the log output.

Comment: Does that mean the `Logcat` info I posted does not tell me anything?

Comment: All it says is that the heap is 10 mb and after the garbage collector ran 25% of 10mb is free. The heap can grow beyond 10mb so that is not an issue. If you saw your heap constantly grow or so many GC calls that it cause performance issues, then i would worry, that output on its own doesn't suggest anything good or bad.